# com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+ and setCustomAnimations

Tags: android-animation, android-support-library

I replace fragments in my application by next code

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
                .replace(R.id.main, newFragment)
                .addToBackStack(Tag)
                .commit();
```

When I uncomment

```
.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, 
R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
```

I've got Fatal Error, but it worked before well. I think the reason in AndroidStudio (current ver 1.5.1, SDK or libs). Code stopped working suddenly, but continues to work after compiling on another PC with  AndrodStudio 1.5
The only way to reinstall Android Studio hoping that it helps me. But I wanna understand what happened.
   The first problem was this:
[can't access to TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800395/cant-access-to-textview)

This code worked ok too.

Maybe somebody can explain what wrong

-- enter_from_left.xml ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

--- enter_from_right.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

--- exit_to_left.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

--- exit_to_right.xml ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: , PID: 24774
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2939)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13368)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13311)
                                                                at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13415)
                                                                at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
                                                                at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2420)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2292)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1922)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1039)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know? the reason in th ADK version, everything work at last version     compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

Everything ok on another AndroidStudio, all problems started after update to Android N

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404504/android-set-custom-animations

Comment: Thanx but it didn't help me  getSupportFragmentManager() worked ok before and getFragmentManager() incompatible with my animation "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: , PID: 2537
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animator name: translate"

Comment: Ok. I helped as follows:                 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.lContainer, new NewsFragment(), "NewsFragment").commit();
                getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

Answer (score 0):

I've removed one row "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+" from build.gradle and everething work ok

```
dependencies {

   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}
```

I don't know why, just by successive exclusions

And everything ok if I use

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```